# Regular Expression in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need to extract the 4th field value (128) from the following line using regular expression.

```
( '29/11/2010 09:38:05', '41297', '29/11/2010 09:40:30', '128', '17', 'SUCCESS', '30', 'e', '9843171457', '1', '-1')
```

Please tell me the way to take the 4th value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can quotes be escaped? If so, how?

Comment: Since this is a comma separated string with quoted values, it makes sense to use a module designed to handle it, not a regex or a split. See eugene's answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV) from CPAN:

```
my $input = "( '29/11/2010 09:38:05', '41297', '29/11/2010 09:40:30', '128', '17', 'SUCCESS', '30', 'e', '9843171457', '1', '-1')";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
    quote_char       => "'",
    always_quote     => 1,
    allow_whitespace => 1,
});
$csv->parse($input);
my @columns = $csv->fields();
print $columns[3], "\n"; # 128
```

Comment: When I tried this, I got some padding, the string was `" '128'"`, e.g. a space plus the single quotes. Was going to check if there's a way to strip that with the module, but it's your answer now. ;)

Comment: +1 Very nice. I'll have to remember that to next time, so I can type faster. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The brute force way:

```
/'[^']*',\s*'[^']*',\s*'[^']*',\s*'([^']*)'/
```

This is a quote, followed by any number of non-quotes, then another quote, a comma, and some optional whitespace. All that is repeated four times with `()` around the fourth value to capture it. This may not work if the values are allowed to have quotes in them.

As Cameron pointed out, you can avoid the repetition using:

```
/(?:'[^']*',\s*){3}'([^']*)'/
```

The `?:` tells the regexp parser *not* to capture the stuff inside the brackets.

Might be easier to split the list up using `split` with the comma as the delimiter, and then take the fourth element. Of course, if you can have commas inside the values, that may not work.

Comment: If he's guaranteed to have tic-comma-tic, that's a better delimiter to use than just the comma ... it fails to strip the beginning and end parenthesis for the first and last field, but makes the command pretty easy, unless I'm missing some requirements ;).

Comment: This can be shortened to `/(?:'[^']*',\s*){3}'([^']*)'/`

Comment: Thanks @Cameron - I've updated my answer with your improvement.

Answer (score 1):

It's just perl's "split" command

```
$str = ('29/11/2010 09:38:05','41297','29/11/2010 09:40:30','128','17','SUCCESS','30','e', '9843171457','1','-1');

@vars = split(/','/,$str);
print "${vars[3]}\n";
```

Comment: Since the values are comma separated and quoted, it makes sense to use a module, like [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm)

Comment: Agreed ... all depends on his requirements.